# Trace flag 1802 and SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I wonder if anybody out there are using trace flag 1802 in production on SQL Server 2016?
I also wonder if trace flag 1802 is officially supported by Microsoft?

When searching if trace flag 1802 is officially supported by Microsoft I only find information regarding SQL Server 2005.

I've tested it in dev and the trace flag still works in SQL Server 2016 but I'm wondering if it's officially supported so I don't run into unexpected problems if I start using it in prod on SQL Server 2016 machines.

Comment: why would anyone actually be using that trace flag?!? "FIX: After you detach a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database that resides on network-attached storage, you cannot reattach the SQL Server database"

Comment: hehe... I understand you question.
We have an application on a number of SQL Servers where users are detaching and attaching databases themselves, not ideally but it's vendor specific, so I need to find a solution for it. The problem is when one user detaches a database and another tries to attach the database it doesn't work. I don't allow users to be local admin on my servers so this is way of handling it.

Comment: sounds like madness!

Comment: Well, that's one way of putting it…
Unfortunately I don’t have the possibility to change application or vendor, it is what it is for the foreseeable future. I’m interested in finding a way to solve the problem for now and then in a longer perspective try to motivate the system owner to find other solutions.

Comment: The fact that this flag [isn't listed](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql) in the standard list of flags suggests that you're on your own. If it works, it works; if it doesn't work, it's unlikely resources will be made available to fix problems unless you have a bag of money to offer. This flag was created to work around one particular issue at one particular time; it may be dropped at any point if supporting it becomes inconvenient.